# A sufficient criterion for a finite group to be a Frobenius group

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups

Suppose that $G$ has a non-trivial proper subgroup $H$ such that the following holds: Whenever $1 \ne X \le H$, then $N_G(X) \le H$. Then $G$ is a Frobenius group with Frobenius complement $H$.

> Let $p \in \pi(H)$. First we show that $H$ contains a Sylow $p$-subgroup of $G$. For this let $P \in Syl_p(H)$. Then $P \ne 1$ and therefore $N_G(P) \le H$, so in particular $P \in Syl_p(N_G(P))$. Now assume there exists a Sylow $p$-subgroup $Q$ of $G$ which contains $P$ proper, i.e. $P < Q$, then $P < N_Q(P)$, because normalisers of proper subgroups of $p$-groups grow. But $N_Q(P) = N_G(P) \cap Q$, so that $N_Q(P)$ is a $p$-subgroup of $N_G(P)$ which contains $P$ proper, i.e. $P$ is not a Sylow $p$-subgroup of $N_G(P)$, this contradiciton yields $P \in Syl_p(G)$.
>
> Now let $g \in G$ and suppose that $x \in H\cap H^g$ is a non-trivial $p$-element. Without loss $x \in P$. Then by hypothesis if follows first that $Z(P) \le H\cap H^g$ and then that $P \le H\cap H^g$. In particular $P$ and $P^{g^{-1}}$  are Sylow $p$-subgroups of $H$. Let $h \in H$ be such that $P^h = P^{g^{-1}}$. Then $P^{hg} = P$ whence $hg \in N_G(P) \le H$ by hypothesis. We deduce that $g \in H$, so $H = H^g$.
>
> Therefore if $g \notin H$ we must have $H\cap H^g = 1$, and this means that $G$ is a Frobenius group with $H$ as Frobenius complement. $\square$

The first part of the second paragraph I do not understand "[...] $x \in H\cap H^g$ is a non-trivial $p$-element. Without loss $x \in P$. Then by hypothesis if follows first that $Z(P) \le H\cap H^g$ and then that $P \le H\cap H^g$ [...]". As $Z(P) \le N_G(\langle x \rangle)$ is see that $Z(P) \le H$, but why $Z(P) \le H^g$, and why does $Z(P) \le H\cap H^g$ implies $P \le H^\cap H^g$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The hypothesis holds for $H^g$ as well as for $H$, so $Z(P) \le H^g$ for exactly the same reason that $Z(P) \le H$.

We have $P \le N_G(Z(P)) \le H$ and similarly $P \le H^g$.

By the way, you mean "criterion" not "criteria", which is plural.

Comment: Do you really mean $P\le N_H(Z(P))$ or $P \le N_G(Z(P))$? And yes, thanks I corrected my misspelling!

Comment: I meant $N_G(Z(P))$ - corrected!